# PostgreSQL - export output to CSV

Tags: postgresql

I want to export a queried table to CSV file. The query syntax written here is not my codes. I got it from my co-worker. My knowledge with PostgreSQL is very minimal, and I don't know how to modify the code. Please give me a working code that can export the queried table into CSV. Formats aren't important as long as its in CSV format, as I can use Python to reformat the tables.

```
WITH es_events AS
  (SELECT *
   FROM dblink('foreign_rs_server', $EXT$
           -- Note that since device_id and register_id are known and singular, 
        -- they are replaced as constant values rather than retrieved.
        -- As a distributed columnar store, Redshift is most performant when fewer columns are retrieved.
               SELECT DATE("dt")::timestamp as dt, value, 2777 as device_id, 1343 as register_id
               FROM "es_events" AS "events"
                             WHERE "events"."event_type" = 0
                             AND register_id = 1343
                             AND device_id=2777 
                             AND dt>='2018-12-01T00:00:00' 
                             AND dt<'2018-12-02T00:00:00'
               ORDER BY DATE("dt") ASC; $EXT$) AS es_events (dt TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, value DOUBLE PRECISION, device_id INTEGER, register_id INTEGER)),
register_versions AS
(
    SELECT 
        r.*,
        r.valid_at as valid_start,
        CASE
        WHEN r2.valid_at IS NULL THEN '2020-01-01'
        ELSE r2.valid_at
        END as valid_end
    FROM registers r
    LEFT JOIN registers r2 ON r2.id=r.id AND r2.valid_at>r.valid_at
    ORDER BY id ASC 
)

SELECT "dt",
             r.name,
             "events"."value"*r.scaling as scaled_value,
             r.units_of_measure
FROM "es_events" AS "events"
JOIN register_versions r ON r.id = events.register_id AND (r.valid_start <= dt AND r.valid_end > dt)
JOIN device_asset_mapping dam ON dam.device_id=events.device_id AND dam.active
ORDER BY dam.asset_id, dt ASC
```

Comment: CSV export is a feature that is implemented by the SQL client you are using. In `psql` you could do it using the `\copy` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use terminal command like this :

```
COPY ( your query inside ) TO 'C:\tmp\persons_email_db.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

or you can simply use some Database Tools like navicat or dbeaver to run your query above and export the result to csv